# Value insertion into list using JAVA 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (long i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
        list.add(i);
    }



}
```

this loop taking too long to insert values into the list is there any features in JAVA 8, using that the same task will perform in a minimal time.

Comment: the bigger question would be what do you want to do with that `List` of (100000000 -1) elements? Just iterating on them is feasible using `LongStream.iterate` as well.

Comment: That is really a big number, try multi threading and split the loop in two or more threads :) but it won't be in order

Comment: Please use the linkedlist
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java

Comment: This can be improved significantly by using `long[] list = new long[100000000];`, declaring `i` as `int` in the loop, and `list[i] = i;` (unless you need a list, which is unlikely)

Comment: @DickensAS Yes I did it with multithreading using join. But looking to do the same using Java 8. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Why do you want a list of the numbers from 0 to 99999999? What is the use-case?

Comment: Please look into Multithreading.

Comment: @Naman Thanks for suggesting LongStream.iterate. Running code using this. Lets lee how much time it takes. If anything else you want to suggest will be appreciated.:)

Comment: @kaya3 running this code to check if any features in JAVA 8 parallel stream to perform this instead of multithreading.

Comment: The way to build a list using streams will depend on what you want to put in the list. The main benefit of building a list in parallel will be if computing the items themselves takes the bulk of the time. In your example, the bottleneck is just the time it takes to add the item to the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the fastest way to initialize a large list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845767/whats-the-fastest-way-to-initialize-a-large-list-of-integers)

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating a list of hundred millions of items? And that each item will be an wrapper object?

Answer (score 0):

If it’s not mandatory that the list be an `ArrayList`:

```
    Long[] array = new Long[100_000_000];
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(array, Long::valueOf);
    List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

I have not done any time measurements. The list will be modifiable in the sense that you can set values, but it has fixed size, there is no adding or removing.

If you do need a variable-size list, you may try:

```
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(array));
```

It somewhat defies the idea of exploiting parallel execution, though, and I am no longer sure about how the speed would compare to what you have already got.

Edit: If the list doesn’t need to be modifiable at all, make your own “list” implementation that doesn’t store any actual data and calculates the value each time an element is asked for. Then initialization will take no time. You can subclass `AbstractList` for this purpose.